# Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2010: Error when trying to open .vcxproj

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Anyone have an idea why this is? I also installed the NVIDIA CUDA SDK and all that. Some googling hasn't yielded me an answer yet...

Or is it just not supported? Do I need to buy another version?

Comment: [Microsoft Visual Studio] '<filepath>.vcxproj' cannot be opened because its project type (.vcxproj) is not supported by this version of the application. To open it, please use a version that supports this type of project. [OK] [Help]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to say without the actual error message, but my guess would be that you're using the wrong version of Visual Studio Express. You'll need Visual C++ 2010 Express available here: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads